# Combine multiple workbooks according to a given criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have difficulties writing a VBA code for a situation I am facing with. Below, I will give a short example.

I have a folder with multiple files and they are saved with the following name format:

```
12345XX_103_P05 
12345XX_142_P05
12345XX_ROOT_P05
55555XX_919_P05
55555XX_70_P05
55555XX_ROOT_P05
```

I need to combine these workbooks into other files taking into consideration only a part of their names (12345XX or 55555XX) as a merging criteria

```
12345XX_103_P05 
12345XX_142_P05
12345XX_ROOT_P05
```

must be merged into one file named 12345XX, for each WB I need a separate worksheet.

```
55555XX_919_P05
55555XX_70_P05
55555XX_ROOT_P05
```

must be merged into another file named 55555XX, for each WB I need a separate worksheet.

Is there a Macro that can help me? If more details are needed, please let me know.

Comment: What have you tried? We're not here to do your work. Please share what you've attempted so we can see where it's gone wrong, then we can help

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).